# Website Address Keep redirect to website after migration attempt

Tags: urls, migration

I have a loclhost site that I heard I can migrate the site by just copy and paste the whole site from local to host if I changed WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) to my current hosted site address and then upload it to the host (which I am doing now)

Problem is that now when I try to login my local site it will always redirect to my actual website.

How can I fix my loclhost site setup so it back to its original loclhost address?

============UPDATE====================================
Added below files into the wp-config of the Wordpress:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://localhost/a02business');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://localhost/a02business');
```

Result: When try to login, the page will still be directed to the actual website not my local site....

Help plz

Comment: The update is really a different question. Your original problem was that you broke your _local_ install. The update is about the _remote_ server. Those are different animals and the solutions are likely to be different.

Comment: Ok, got you. I will post another thread for this! Thanks..........and here is my new question location!http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/87062/error-establishing-a-database-connection-after-copy-localhost-wordpress-site-wi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you change the configuration on the local server. You need to put it back. that local configuration information needs to remain unchanged if you intend to continue working on the local copy, which you should. Breaking a local development version of the site is a lot less painful than breaking the live version. :)

The easiest way to sort this out is to add the following two lines to your `wp-config.php` file on your local server.

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com/wordpress');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://example.com/wordpress');
```

Obviously, the domain needs to be changed-- probably to `localhost` but if the local server has a static (internal) IP using the xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx IP is better.

I don't know what else you did so there may be more steps but I hope that fixes it.

For reference:

1. http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress
2. http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_address_.28URL.29

Comment: Wow, that's fast :D thanks :) I am still uploading the file ( tethered internet lol) so, I will try it out once its finished uploading!

Comment: Thank you very much I will update the question status or comment again to let you know :)

Comment: What do you mean "uploading"? You said this was to get a local install working again.

Comment: yes, I change the site url then I upload the site to the host, and its in the middle of the upload, which just finished now. Responding in few min

Comment: *explaination: I uploaded the site after I changed the local url to a hosting server's url, so that why the local will keep direct to the hosting server's url. Now I am trying, brb

Comment: I updated the situation

Comment: Ok, your answer worked! But now I need to resolve the issue with Error database connection for my uploaded site....any suggested thread that I can have more info on it?

Comment: Just search the site. I expect that there is not database, actually. I would suggest you start another question and explicitly, step by step, explain what you did when you tried to move the site.

Comment: Hello, s_ha_dum, just took out the check for your attention. I actually got trouble to login the website, even though it loads, but when I log in, it takes me back to my web hosted site....Could you help me on that? Thanks!

Comment: It is going to be hard to debug particular errors but search the local `*_options` table for the remote domain. Also, flush your browser cache.